# Main thread locking up in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am faced with a problem. I am clicking a button that is calling several methods, although the main thread is locking up, so I created an instance of my class (which is `Form1`) e.g. `Form1Object` and then the button called the methods as so: `Form1Object.Check1` and so on.

Although the thread still locked up (i.e. the GUI became unresponsive for a period) Is there anyway of getting around this, any examples would be greatly appreciated.

The code in question is below:

```
private void StartChecks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 Form1Object = new Form1();
    Form1Object.InitChecks();
}

public void InitChecks()
{
    Check1();
    Check2();
    Check3();
    Check4();
    Check5();
    Check6();
    Check7();
}
```

Comment: You should probably look into using a BackgroundWorker, but in this case it might even be enough to just use Application.DoEvents();.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

Comment: You fix this by running the code on a separate thread. That's how you keep your main (UI) thread from locking up. In fact, you should never run long-running operations on the UI thread precisely *because* it causes the UI to become unresponsive. The solution here seemed obvious from the problem...

Comment: Also, **never use `Application.DoEvents()`**. Can't emphasize that enough. Learn how to do multi-threading (or at least use `BackgroundWorker`) correctly. Don't hack it. Ignore everyone who tells you differently.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, It was simply a typo, I updated it after 5 seconds.

Comment: @CodyGray I can only agree, that is why it comes with a big disclaimer on the MSDN page, and the reason why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @Fuji: Then why post it as a comment? And suggest that "in this case it might even be enough to just use [it]"? Of course it's enough. The problem is that it's quite often *too much*. Most people don't check links or read the documentation; that's why they're asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @CodyGray He asked for a way to get around it so I provided with a possible solution, but suggesting that a BackgroundWorker would be the better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is start a parallel thread to do the check, so you won't lock up the main thread:

```
   private void StartChecks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 Form1Object = new Form1();
        Thread t = new Thread(
           o => 
           {
               Form1Object.InitChecks();
           });
        t.Start();
    }
```

Hopefully you don't need to actually retrieve anything from those calculations, so you can just fire and forget about it.

Comment: Cheers, small typo, "start" needs to be capitalized. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new Form does not start a new Thread.

You will have to move those CheckN() methods to a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

```
private void StartChecks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form1 Form1Object = new Form1();
  var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  worker.DoWork += (s, arg) => 
  {
     Form1Object.InitChecks();
  };

  // add progress, completed events

  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

But note that this require that the checks are independent and do not interact with any Control.

Comment: Cheers, 2 typos BackgroundWorker and you are missing a semicolon (second line from bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here, and use them depending of your skill/preference/requirement:

- if you don't update anything on the form while you process, start another thread and call everything on that thread, and update UI when appropriate (when everything is finished)
- if you need to update things on your form while processing, you have several options:

  - either use `Application.DoEvents()` from the processing loop of every method you use
  - start a new thread then update form controls with `Invoke()` - if you try to update them directly, you'll be in trouble

If you care to comment and decide for one of the options, I can provide more info on just that...